# What am I missing for JS object literal with method?

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

I am trying to create a simple object literal with a method in it, which in this case is a moving block on a canvas. I wrote the following piece of code using a tutorial at http://www.html5rocks.com

```
var block = {
    color: "#000000",
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    draw: function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
};

function update() {
    block.x = block.x + 30;
    block.y = block.y + 30;
}

function draw() {
    var x = document.getElementById("space");
    var ctx = x.getContext("2d");

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 900, 600);

    block.draw();
}
```

For some reason it will not work like this, while it will if I write the code now in the draw method in the draw() function. I'm probably missing something, but what?

Comment: How is the code supposed to get to that "ctx" variable if you don't pass it as a parameter?

Comment: Always look at your console when JavaScript does not work, it probably contains useful errors. @Pointy is not always nearby to tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`block`, and its members, have never heard of `ctx`, which is local to your `draw()` function.

Either make that global, or pass it into `block.draw`:

```
var block = {
  // ...

  draw: function(ctx) { 
    // ...
  }
};

// ...

block.draw(ctx);
```

Comment: `block` is an object and does not even know the concept of a "scope". Only functions can "have heard of a variable" as you put it.

Comment: My humblest apologies for explaining things colloquially. I'm clearly history's worst monster.

Answer (score 1):

`ctx` is not known when the method is declared. the method creates a closure, and has no value for `ctx`. remember that scopes are not precisely dynamic (regarding references), since the scope is defined upon function definition, and not function usage.

how to fix it: pass `ctx` as a parameter to the method, or as an assignable property (and modify the method to reference `this.ctx`)